# Partion function for ideal gas - why use only one octant?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

In these [lecture notes](http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~smao/starHtml/equationState.pdf) (page 2) and in other sources I have checked, it says that the number of states with $k\in[k,k+dk]$ is:
$$dN=\frac{4\pi k^2V}{8\pi^3}$$
Saying the factor of $8$ comes from the fact we only count states in the first octant. Where is the justification behind this? I.e. why are we not using all the octants in the k-phase space (which will give us a different partition function, Helmholtz free energy etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says in the notes

> [...]the factor of 8 arises because we are only counting the states in the quadrangle with positive $n_x$, $n_y$ and $n_z$.

The eigenfunctions of a particle in a box are
$$ \Psi(x) \propto\prod_{j\in{x,y,z}} \sin\left(\frac{n_j}{L_j}x_j\right) $$
with $n_j\in\mathbb{N}$. Choosing $n_j$ a negative integer does not yield a different state, but multiplication by a phase of $(-1)$.

In essence one would count all states eight-fold $(2^3)$ if one were to allow negative $n$ as well. *In fact this is exactly what the $k$-integral does!* Hence one needs to correct for the over-counting.